# Calling a class method from the constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm getting an error when calling a class method from its constructor. Is it possible to call a method from the constructor? I tried calling the base class method from the constructor of a derived class but I am still getting an error.

```
'use strict';

class Base {
    constructor() {
        this.val = 10;
        init();
    }

    init() {
        console.log('this.val = ' + this.val);
    }
};

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
};

var d = new Derived();
```

> ➜  js_programs node class1.js
>   /media/vi/DATA/programs/web/js/js_programs/class1.js:7
>           init();
>           ^
>
> ReferenceError: init is not defined
>       at Derived.Base (/media/vi/DATA/programs/web/js/js_programs/class1.js:7:9)
>       at Derived (/media/vi/DATA/programs/web/js/js_programs/class1.js:18:14)
>       at Object. (/media/vi/DATA/programs/web/js/js_programs/class1.js:23:9)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
>       at startup (node.js:136:18)
>       at node.js:963:3 ➜  js_programs

Comment: Maybe the title should be `Calling a method from constructor` or `Calling a member function from constructor`. A `class method` is a `static` method.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're calling the *function* `init()`, not the *method* `init` of either `Base` or the current object. No such function exists in the current scope or any parent scopes. You need to refer to your object:

```
this.init();
```

Answer (score 17):

You are missing `this` keyword:

```
this.init();
```